# How can i use a angular variable coming from controller in html?

Tags: angularjs

i have a question on how to get variables set in my controller in a html tag?

Example:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" ng-hide="checked">
```

The ng-hide should be a variable. In my controller i have:

```
$scope.checked = "checked";
```

How to use the variable in the above example?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" ng-hide="{{ checked }}">
```

Doesnt work.

Comment: `ng-hide="checked == 'checked'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you this.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function testCtrl ($scope) {
            $scope.checked = true;

            $scope.changeHide = function(){
                $scope.checked = false;
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <div ng-show="checked">
            Must be shown on start.
        </div>
        <button ng-click="changeHide()">Hide</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

ng-show or ng-hide , it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

**ng-hide** **ng-show** **ng-desabled** 
all of them rely on a true/false variable,

So you have to consider a $scope.checked=**false** or **true**  in your controller , and that will work